# How do I read names in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I just encountered this example on learnyouahaskell.com. However, I don't understand it at all.

```
ghci> let xxs = [[1,3,5,2,3,1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,4,2,1,6,3,1,3,2,3,6]]  
ghci> [ [ x | x <- xs, even x ] | xs <- xxs]  
[[2,2,4],[2,4,6,8],[2,4,2,6,2,6]] -- This is the output
```

My problem is that while I do understand the idea of list comprehensions, I don't get what the `xxs` means.
If it was just the name of the list of lists, how can we split up a name and do something like `xs <- xxs`. To me that doesn't make sense at all.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xxs` is the list of lists bound in the let expression.  I think you're being confused by the similarity of `xxs` and `xs`, they are just two independent names with no relation.  You can replace `xs` with `sublist` or any other valid name.

```
ghci> let xxs = [[1,3,5,2,3,1,2,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,2,4,2,1,6,3,1,3,2,3,6]]  
ghci> [ [ x | x <- sublist, even x ] | sublist <- xxs]
```

So we're not splitting on the name we're just using the `<-` list comprehension operator to iterate over the elements of a `[[a]]` and then have another comprehension for iterating over the elements of each `[a]` sublist.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example with `sublist` made it clear to me!

Comment: It's common in Haskell to see things like `x` and `xs` to represent "an element from a list (`x`)" and then "the rest of the list (`xs`)".
In this case, since there's another layer (i.e. it's a list of lists), they use `xxs` (I would have written it `xss`, probably) to extend the same idea.